# Is there a way to define `match` labels using macros?

Tags: rust

I mean, see code

```rust
macro_rules! impls {
    () => {
        let a = "Hello, world!";
        println!("{}", match 7 {
            impls!{ 3 + 4, a }
            _ => unimplemented!()
        })
    };

    ($x:expr, $name:ident) => {
        ($x) => $name,
    }
}

fn main() {
    impls!{ }
}
```

As I think, `impls!{ 3 + 4, a }` should be `(3 + 4) => a`, but it's not. What's wrong?
Compiler error:

```
error: expected one of `=>`, `if`, or `|`, found reserved identifier `_`
  --> src/main.rs:6:13
   |
5  |             impls!{ 3 + 4, a }
   |                               - expected one of `=>`, `if`, or `|`
6  |             _ => unimplemented!()
   |             ^ unexpected token
...
16 |     impls!{ }
   |     --------- in this macro invocation
   |
   = note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Comment: You could add `match` to your `impls` makro and pass the actual item to match to the macro as well.

Comment: Btw: `3 + 4` is not a valid match pattern, so you can't use that either way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not possible with declarative macros (it might be with procedural macros, I've very little experience with those so I do not know): per [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html)

> Macros can expand to expressions, statements, items (including traits, impls, and foreign items), types, or patterns.

A *match arm* is not in and of itself a "Rust construct", it's a sub-item of a `match` expression (composed of a pattern, an optional guard expression and a body expression).

As a result, it can not be produced by a declarative macro.

Answer (score 0):

While macros cannot expand to match arm, as said, it is still possible to use them for patterns:[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=10ebf7b2ab59c2741289ca6cefea12a2)

```
struct A(usize);
struct B(f32);
macro_rules! impls {
    () => {
        let x =  A(3 + 4);
        println!("{}", match x {
            impls!{ A -> 7 } => "Hello,",
            _ => unimplemented!(),
        })
    };
    ($e:expr) => {
        let x =  B(4.0);
        println!("{}", match x {
            impls!{ B -> x } => if x==$e { "world!" } else {"None"},
        })
    };
    
    ($a:tt -> $x:tt) => { $a($x) };
}

fn main() {
    impls!{ }
    impls!{ 16f32.sqrt() }
    impls!{ }
    impls!{ 1.0 }
}
```